# /etc/fstab fails to bind mount on boot, but running mount -a works correctly

Tags: debian, mount, fstab, bind-mount

I'm running a modified WD MyCloud (Gen 1) NAS with Debian 8 (Jessie) installed on it.

Due to the nuances of the device, I can't resize the root partition, and am struggling with space on it.

To remedy this, I've rsynced the `/var` and `/usr` directories on to the main data partition.

I've then added the following lines to the `/etc/fstab`:

```
/data/rootfs/var    /var    none    defaults,bind    0    0
/data/rootfs/usr    /usr    none    defaults,bind    0    0
```

Upon rebooting, I find that the `/var` directory has **successfully** been mounted, but that the `/usr` directory **has not**.

If I then run `mount -a`, I get no errors, and the `/usr` directory is correctly mounted.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using systemd, mounts are done in parallel (by [dynamically converting the fstab entries into mount units](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html#fstab)), line ordering is not preserved as would be expected from pre-systemd experience.

You have an untold dependency that's not automatically guessed: mounting `/data/` before mounting `/usr`. WIthout it you get a race condition.

You have to manually add the dependency as a pseudo mount option, using [`x-systemd.requires=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html#fstab). So if the previous mountpoint that should be mounted is `/data`, this should make it work:

```
/data/rootfs/var    /var    none    x-systemd.requires=/data,bind    0    0
/data/rootfs/usr    /usr    none    x-systemd.requires=/data,bind    0    0
```

In case somebody else finds this question, but the use case is for `/data` being a remote network filesystem like NFS, the pseudo mount option `_netdev` (pre-systemd option also recognized by systemd) must *also* be added on the `/data/rootfs/usr` entry to get everything working fine, because `none` can't hint this automatically and not having it might then confuse the `x-systemd.requires=` resolution.