# Cannot mount CIFS share on boot (from /etc/fstab) if it depends on ip route

Tags: debian, mount, cifs, nas

On a **Debian Linux 10** I have a CIFS share defined in `/etc/fstab`:

```
//192.168.120.1/Share /mnt/Share cifs credentials=/etc/fstab-share.password,auto,nofail 0 0
```

On system boot this share does not mount because of:

```
$ systemctl status mnt-Share.mount
● mnt-Share.mount - /mnt/Share
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-10-04 18:48:21 CEST; 23s ago
    Where: /mnt/Share
     What: //192.168.130.130/UnifiRecorder
     Docs: man:fstab(5)
           man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)

Oct 04 18:48:21 home-docker systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt/Share...
Oct 04 18:48:21 home-docker mount[397]: mount error(101): Network is unreachable
Oct 04 18:48:21 home-docker mount[397]: Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
Oct 04 18:48:21 home-docker systemd[1]: mnt-Share.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Oct 04 18:48:21 home-docker systemd[1]: mnt-Share.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 04 18:48:21 home-docker systemd[1]: Failed to mount /mnt/Share.
```

However if I run `systemctl start mnt-Share.mount` after logging in, everything is fine:

```
$ systemctl status mnt-Share.mount
● mnt-Share.mount - /mnt/Share
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; generated)
   Active: active (mounted) since Mon 2021-10-04 18:48:59 CEST; 1s ago
    Where: /mnt/Share
     What: //192.168.130.130/UnifiRecorder
     Docs: man:fstab(5)
           man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 372.0K
   CGroup: /system.slice/mnt-Share.mount

Oct 04 18:48:59 home-docker systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt/Share...
Oct 04 18:48:59 home-docker systemd[1]: Mounted /mnt/Share.
```

I do have a specific route set up to reach my NAS in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug ens18
iface ens18 inet dhcp
    up ip route add 192.168.120.0/24 via 192.168.1.1
```

I suspect that the static **ip route** is set up too late, am I right? Can I configure dependencies correctly in `/etc/fstab` somehow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does \_netdev mount option in /etc/fstab work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169697/how-does-netdev-mount-option-in-etc-fstab-work)

Comment: See also this Q/A with an answer of mine for more complex setups: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486777/etc-fstab-fails-to-bind-mount-on-boot-but-running-mount-a-works-correctly

Comment: @A.B Wow, _netdev solved the problem indeed. I modified my mount this way `//192.168.120.1/Share /mnt/Share cifs credentials=/etc/fstab-share.password,auto,nofail,_netdev 0 0` If you change your comment to an answer I'll accept it right away.

Comment: My 1st comment is a proposal for duplicate question (I don't feel like writing such answer when it's already available, but I don't mind if the proposal isn't accepted in the end and anybody else writes something).

Comment: Ok I did upvote the comment, at least. Thanks again!